# Copy xonsh history to a new computer

Tags: xonsh

With bash I can just copy `.bash_history` from my old computer to the new one.

What should I do in xonsh?

The xonsh's [history tutorial](http://xon.sh/tutorial_hist.html) mentions that the history is stored in the json file indicated by the command `history file`. But I have the impression that this file points to other ones. So, I'm not sure which files I should bring to the new computer to preserve the history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `history file` command shows you the history file for the current *session* only in xonsh.  xonsh uses a single history file per terminal emulator instance (unless you are using a custom back-end).
If you want to copy over your xonsh history to a new computer, copy `xonsh` folder inside the directory specified by the env-var `$XDG_DATA_HOME`.  That's where all of the history files live (by default it's `~/.local/share` on posix-y systems)

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.